# How to check Scroll Position with console?

Tags: javascript, browser, console, scrolltop

I thought I could use the browser console to check the scrollTop position of an element.  I haven't been able to do it though.

I tried window.scrollTop; but I couldn't get anything.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `window.pageXOffset` or `window.pageYOffset`
[Check the window object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp)

The method your are trying to use is from [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/).